# PHP passing Array

Tags: php

I have two php page.
In the first I have looping checkbox array :

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cek[]" value=" <?php echo "$kodeinventarisit"  ?>"></td>`
```

Then i submit form from page one to page two :

```
<?php 
include 'koneksi.php';
$cek = $_POST['cek'];
$jumlah_dipilih = count($cek);

for($x=0;$x<$jumlah_dipilih;$x++){
    $jojo = $cek[$x];
    $coba = "select * from msstok where kodeinventarisit = '$jojo' ";
    $cobaquery = mysql_query($coba);
    $hasil = mysql_fetch_array($cobaquery);
    $jenis = $hasil['jenis'];
    ?>
    <input name="kode" type="text" id="license" value="<?php echo htmlentities($jenis) ; ?>" readonly="readonly" />
    <?php
    echo "$jojo";

}

?>
```

The problem is in the sql query return nothing, I try echo "$jojo" and it's print the value but in the text field is empty..

Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this?
Thank You Very Much

Comment: what will get `$_POST['cek']` !!

Comment: before you do anything, refactor out the old, deprecated, highly insecure mysql driver.  Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to pass the array you need to check if arrive in you second page.**

```
<pre>
    print_r($_POST['cek']);
</pre>
```

**Now, if arrive here, you can read the values like this:**

```
<?php
// If is array(), then you can go to loop
if(is_array($_POST['cek']))
{
    // Run the loop
    foreach($_POST['cek'] as $value)
    {
        // Show values per line
        echo $value. "<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

**You can read only 1 value of your array**

```
<?php echo $_POST['cek'][0]; ?>
<?php echo $_POST['cek'][1]; ?>
<?php echo $_POST['cek'][2]; ?>
```

**Conclusion**

You can't pass array to SQL in query. If you want to use it, this is the only way with implode.

```
$coba = "SELECT * FROM msstok WHERE kodeinventarisit IN (".implode(',', $jojo).")";


$records = mysql_query($coba, $connection); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)) {
   echo "Name: " . $rows['name'] . "<br />"; // replace the name for column you want
}
```

Comment: it is arrive, but when i want to use the array value in the sql where query, in $coba it is return nothing..

Comment: You can't pass array to SQL in query. If you want to use it, this is the only way with implode.

$QueryStr = "SELECT * FROM msstok WHERE kodeinventarisit IN (".implode(',', $jojo).")";

Comment: i tried it, get an error at the sql query line : Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Comment: This is other error, i'll pass the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**1**

What you are doing is bad.

Load your data before your loop and loop every result to print them.

**2**

Protect your sql request from injection.

**Connect**

```
$db  = new mysqli("","root","","");
```

**Prepare your request**

```
$sql = "select * from msstok where kodeinventarisit = ? "; 
$res = $db->prepare($sql); 
$res->bind_param("sssd",$jojo);
```

**Get results**

```
$res->execute();
```

Documentation :  http://php.net/manual/fr/book.mysql.php